# Is there a way to restart the D-Bus on CentOS 7 - without crashing the system?

Tags: centos, centos7, dbus

On *CentOS 7,* doing `sudo systemctl restart messagebus`[1], will bring the system to its knees.
**Is there a way to restart the D-Bus without crashing the system?**

[1] This is dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus.

Comment: Why do you even want to do this at all? This sounds like you're trying to [solve the wrong problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: @Michael: We have a debugging tool that interacts with the D-Bus. The tool won't start after its service is enabled and started for the first time, unless the machine is rebooted. This reboot is needed for restarting the D-Bus. I'm trying to see if there's a way to restart the D-Bus - without a full machine reboot.

Comment: Sounds like the debugging tool needs to be debugged. Perhaps its vendor can help.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK It is not possible, restarting dbus mean breaking ipc between all process which is similar to reboot itself.